# xcode 6 remains stationary while compiling the last source file

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode6

I have problems when I try to do a Build or Archive  with Xcode 6. I'm not getting any error, Xcode is not freezed; if I do a build on the simulator goes all right (just slow 5 / 6min) and the same when I try on an iPhone 5 goes all right. 
Instead  in iPhone 5s remains locked as when I try to Archive.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen when there are very large files to compile. 
If you are using tools for managing graphics that generate classes check if the resulting file is huge!

Comment: Solved! The graphics have been generated with PaintCode, the StyleKit generated was 40,000 lines; This blocks the compilation and slowed Xcode! Thanks!